# Can i call platform channel from another app in flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, sdk

I am developing an app in flutter and I want to use an SDK which isn't available for flutter and they have a sample project which is written in java (android native) and I want to integrate that app to my current flutter app, is that possible to be done with platform channels?

My experience in the android native is very weak so I almost can pick up with that project.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's your own app though, not another one. And it's not necessary, but Android Studio will help you.

You have to modify the /android project of your Flutter project. You need to implement the SDK in question, and copy/paste/refactor the relevant sample code. You can then expose this code to the Flutter side via a method channel. To learn how, [read this doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

**Important : Hot Restart will not update native code**. You have to recompile everytime you want to apply native code changes.